# Prism Behaviors - Using EventToCommandBehavior with a Button

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to call a method set in my ViewModel using Prism. I bound my EventToCommandBehavior on a Button, but when I click on my button, nothing happens. I've already tested my method, and it works, so I really think this is a problem with my EventToCommandBehavior.

XAML :

```
<controls:FloatingActionButton HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" Image="ic_add.png" ButtonColor="#3BE2CA" Grid.Column="1" Margin="160,45,0,40">
    <controls:FloatingActionButton.Behaviors>
        <b:EventToCommandBehavior                         
             EventName="Clicked"
             Command="{Binding AddToLibraryCommand}"/>
    </controls:FloatingActionButton.Behaviors>
</controls:FloatingActionButton>
```

Method in ViewModel :

```
private DelegateCommand _addToLibraryCommand;

public DelegateCommand AddToLibraryCommand =>
    _addToLibraryCommand ?? (_addToLibraryCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteAddToLibraryCommand));
```

Yeah, my Button is not really a Button, it's a FloatingActionButton  which inherits the Button class downloaded from SuavePirate's repository : 
https://github.com/SuavePirate/Xamarin.Forms.Controls.FloatingActionButton

I tried to use my Behavior with a classic Button, and also with the *Command* attribute, but it's not working neither.
 Can someone explain me where is the problem?

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Since FloatingActionButton inherits Button class, why don't you use _Command_ property?

Comment: Because it doesn't work

Comment: I meant not a Behavior, a raw Command. <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/> or <FloatingActionButton Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>

Comment: Yeah I understand, and it doesn't work ^^ That's why I wanted to use an EventToCommandBehavior

Comment: Does it work in _code-behind_ way? And also how are you setting up the viewModel of your Xaml?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using MVVM architecture, so I assume I'm already using the code-behind way :/
I'm using "xmlns" tags in my XAML page.

My XAML is perfectly linked with my ViewModel, I can use other methods declared in my ViewModel and it's working ^^ But for some reason, I cannot trigger this method when clicking on my Button

Comment: Can you clarify "it does not work"?

Comment: When I click on my Button, my method is not triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, I found where was my error : 
The Button tried to get my Command on the wrong class, because my Button was in a ListView, and this ListView changed the Button's BindingContext. So I had to manually set the BindingContext for the Button.

```
<controls:FloatingActionButton x:Name="FAB" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10"
                                                                   ButtonColor="#3BE2CA" 
                                                                   Grid.Column="1" 
                                                                   Margin="160,45,0,40" 
                                         <!-- Added this line -->  BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference BookList}, Path=BindingContext}"
                                                                   Command="{Binding AddToLibraryCommand}"/>
```

Thank you for your help!